# OpenGL shader effect

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fbo

I need a efficient openGL pipeline to achieve a specific look of the line segment shapes.

This is a look I am aiming for:
[image]
(https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdX3WN)

This is one of the primitives (spiral) I already have inside my program:

[image: spiral]

Inside gl_FragColor for this picture I am outputting distance from fragment to camera. The pipeline for this is the usual VBO->VAO->Vertex shader->Fragment shader path.

The shadertoy shader calculates the distance to the 3 points in every fragment of the screen and outputs the color according to that. But in my example I would need this in a reverse. Calculate color for surrounding fragments for ever fragment of spiral (in this case). Is it necessary to go with a render a scene into a texture using a FBO or is there a shortcut?

Comment: What does "VBA" mean?  When you say 3 points, which points are you talking about?

Comment: I mean VAO - Vertex Array Object. The 3 points I am talking about are the red blue green points from the shadertoy example.

Comment: The approach you are suggesting for the spiral makes it sound like you do not understand how fragment shaders work. You do a computation per fragment and you can only determine the color for the current fragment. You can not change surrounding fragments.

Answer (score 1):

1. **For small limited number of lines**

   use single quad covering the area or screen as geometry and send the lines points coordinates and colors to shader as **1D** texture(s) or `uniform`. Then you can do the computation inside fragment shader per pixel an all lines at once. Higher line count will slow things down considerably.
2. **For higher number of lines**

   you need to convert your geometry from lines to rectangles covering affected surroundings of a line:

   [image: quad example]

   use transparency to merge the lines correctly and compute color from perpendicular distance from the line. Add the dots from distance from the endpoints (can be done with texture instead of shader).

   Your image suggest that the light affects whole screen so in that case you need to call Quad covering whole screen per each line instead of a rectangle coverage

Answer (score 1):

In the end I used:

- CatmullRom spline interpolation to get point data from control points
- Build VBO from above points
- Vortex shader: pass point position data
- Geometry shader: emit sprite size quads for every point
- Fragment shader: use exp function to get a smooth gradient color from the center of the sprite quad

Result is something like this:

[image]

with:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);  // additive blend
```

It renders to FBO with GL_RGBA16 for more smoothness.